# Effects of closing a Black Hole in a solar system (let's say ours?)

Tags: science-based, black-holes

Lets say for instance an alien civilization decided to drop an artificial star on the edge of our solar system's Heliosphere, resize it 20x the size of ours, implode it into a black hole but omit the crushing supernova.

Finally after a week of watching they decide to remove the Black hole.

What would happen to our solar system during and after that time?
What would happen to our physical bodies if anything?
Would our System ever normalize, and how long would it take?

Comment: How do you 'extinguish the thing by killing the core'? That statement does not make sense when applied to a black hole.

Comment: Also, a star the size of ours cannot form a black hole, it is not massive enough.

Comment: Also if it were massive enough to form a black hole (it isn't) the explosion that formed the black hole (a supernova) would obliterate the solar system.

Comment: I have a feeling that having a black hole that astronomically close to the solar system will almost always end in swift Earth-wide death. Having an object that massive appear would cause such huge gravitational changes that the entire planet would shift. Imagine a ball slowly rolling across the ground on a nice even pace and then quickly being kicked at high speed. The sudden change in direction or momentum would just end everything.

Comment: What do you think would happen to our non-physical bodies? Just curious.

Comment: Though this does not answer your question, something you should note is that the gravitational effect of a size 20 star would be equal to the gravitational effect of a black hole formed from a 100% mass collapse of a size 20 star. They would both contain the same amount of mass and hence have the same gravitational and time dilation effects. Your question is what those effects are. I'm just pointing out that the gravity wouldn't change between a star and a black hole.

Comment: Sorry for the vote, but there are too many unknowns. What do you mean by "dropping a star"? How did it get there, what was its route and speed? What do you mean by size? Mass? volume? Radius? How was it removed? Things like that.

Comment: The "unclear" question is a twenty sol mass star "appears' at the outer edge of the helioshere. Let's forget about the black hole bit, mass is mass irrespective of its form. One week later the 20 sol mass object "vanishes". What is its effect on the solar system? Seems simple enough, eh? Assume for simplicity the mass is "teleported" in & out. Aliens are like that.

Comment: @Crashie-J Welcome to Worldbuilding. I have reworded your question for clarity. See my comment above. I recommend you re-edit your question accordingly and you might get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot at this, with the caveats: I am *not* an astrophysicist, and, If you're not already familiar with the concepts, 
Kardashev Type III Civilization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale)  ;
Schwarzschild Radius [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) and 
a little reading on matter conversion at black hole event horizons.

As you are no doubt aware our 'Solar System' doesn't exactly 'end' 
at a specific place, the Oort cloud is comparatively *loaded* with matter, comets, planet sized chunks of proto-solar left overs, etc.  While I agree with the above comment about gravitational disruption, my primary concern would be the gamma and x-ray emission from Oort matter being drawn in and partially emitted as high energy radiation.  The gravitational effects in a week would depend on where the new object was, and would be essentially irreversible  ( unless our new Pals from Type III want to reverse it).  The radiation damage would begin within perhaps a day and would persist as long after it is gone, Earth quite possibly sterilized. 
  No recovery.